# Magento invoice emails

Tags: php, magento, invoice

is there anybody who is able to tell me how exactly I can make Magento automatically send an custom html invoice email containing some custom variables like tax number?

Really appreciate it!

Comment: I guess this will help: http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/customizing-transactional-emails

Answer (score 0):

You need to override Invoice Controller `app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\controllers\Sales\Order\InvoiceController.php`, when admin create an Invoice ans email will go to that customer.

How to override Admin Controller help: http://www.placementquestion.com/tutorial/magento/override_admin_controller_in_magento

Hope will help!